# IE reverting from 11 to older version in order to fix issues

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

1. So my current problem Im facing is that on IE 11 when I select the
   products tab and go to the link, I'm unable to open up the drop
   downs for each product section to view the products within.
2. I currently have a small code in place in order to detect what
   version of IE is currently being ran and displaying a message on the
   header of the page instructing users what to do to fix the problem
   easily from their end. What I'm trying to accomplish is to implement
   a JS code that automatically detects what version they're running
   and if its a version I know isn't working properly, I want it to
   automatically change it's self to a version where it functions
   properly in without the user having to do anything.
3. I know it runs properly in all other browser and in earlier versions
   of IE such as 10, 9, 8,etc. But 11 is the only one that has issues.
4. Here's the current code I have in place in the header section in
   order to inform the user what to do:`<!--[if IE 11]>

       <div class="phone-num" style=" left: 230px; ">
           <p> If you're using IE11 click settings, click compatibility view, select add then close. </p>
       </div>
       <![endif]-->`
5. In the meta code above i have it listed out this way:`<meta
   http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1,EmulateIE9">`
6. I have searched other spots in order to find something to help me
   compile something but as far as I've found everyone else is just
   running codes to test and see what version is currently running and
   to let the user know what it is, or what to do.

Comment: maybe your meta content is flawed. Did you read first answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e/6771584#6771584

Comment: @yezzz I did, but got a little confused would it not function properly with multiple references in the meta content?

Comment: well perhaps you could try content= with "IE=10" or "IE=EmulateIE10", though they say you shouldn't use document modes in ie11. Maybe it's possible to work around the issue with js, but you'd have to post a new question with details.

Comment: see the issue is im working this off a mac and dont have IE currently installed on here, but when i try it that method only IE=EmulateIE10 the selections will function but will have a black background instead of the color red which is supposed to be there. When i try it in the DEV mode of safari it doesnt work, so im confused on if this method even works at all or a JS would be better.

Comment: well obviously can't help without code, so post a new question ([ask]) and maybe someone can come up with a fix.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10,9,8,7">
```

or, if compatibility view is OK, this might work:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
```